# example for $\varphi(H \cap K) \subset \varphi(H)\cap \varphi(K)$, $H, K< G$ and $\varphi \in Hom(G,G')$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ and $\varphi \in Hom(G,G')$

Give an  example of  $\varphi(H \cap K) \subseteq \varphi(H)\cap \varphi(K)$ for which the inclusion holds strictly.

I have already proved the relation, and tried a few examples but all I can come up with are examples in which they are equal.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Try abelian subgroups $H$ and $K$ isomorphic to one another such that $G = H \times K$. Can you construct a homomorphism to $G'$ again isomorphic to $H$ (and $K$) with this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example is given by, given an abelian group $A$, take $G=A\times A$ and $G'=A$. Then we define
$$\varphi(g,h)=gh$$
Take $H=A\times\{1\}$, $K=\{1\}\times A$. Then the intersection is trivial, but the intersection of the images is the whole group.

As per Sebastian Schoennenbeck's example, one can take any symmetric group $S_n$ and have the homomorphism $\varphi:S_n\to\mathbb\{-1,1\}$ be the sign homomorphism. Then for example if we have the transpositions $(12)$ and $(23)$, the corresponding subgroups of order $2$ intersect trivially, but the images of the two subgroups are the same and are the whole image of the homomorphism, so the containment is proper.

Comment: Nice! In the case the groups that do not involve the cartesian product of two groups, is it possible to have such a case or does it always fall to the equality?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I'm $100\%$ certain the equality does not always hold in that case, but I don't currently have an example, except for a nontrivial semidirect product of abelian groups.

Comment: The smallest possible group already does the trick luckily. Look at the symmetric group $S_3$ and the sign homomorphism. Then all subgroups of order $2$ have the same image (again of order $2$) but they have pairwise trivial intersection.

Comment: Although I just realized this clearly falls under your category of semidirect products of abelian groups @MattSamuel. However, the same still holds true for larger symmetric groups which are no longer a semidirect product of Abelian groups (though still a semidirect product(

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck Do you mind if I incorporate your example or do you want to write your own answer?

Comment: Please go ahead. It makes more sense to have one complete answer that then gets accepted.

Comment: @Matt Samuel How does the sign homomorphism works? and I am still getting familiar with  the symmetric group so, to be explicit: the subgroups of order 2 are each composed of the identity and a trasposition, right? so what would be the subgroup (12) belongs to ? = {(12),(21)} ?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO The sign homomorphism sends a permutation to $-1$ if it has an odd number of inversions and to $1$ if it has an even number (even number is the alternating subgroup). The subgroup corresponding to $(12)$ consists of $(12)$ and the identity, $(12)^2=1$.

Comment: @Matt Samuel {-1,1} is a multiplicative group, right?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO That is correct.